# Create a WordPress site data with Nginx app data automatically

Tags: php, bash, linux, wordpress, nginx

The following script is aimed for Ubuntu `>=16.04` LEMP environments with PHP-FPM `>=7.0`, MySQL, WP-CLI, Certbot, and WordPress apps.

The script get's one domain as an argument and creates the following aspects based on that argument (`drt=document-root`):

1. WP_app directory in drt.
2. WP_installation in drt/domain.
3. WP_conf in drt/domain.
4. NX_app conf in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/`
5. NX_symlink in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`
6. NX_certbot configuration.

`${drt}` = document root.

---

One could then add a database stack via MySQL, accordingly (and also edit the website files, accordingly).

```
#!/bin/bash
domain="$1" && test -z ${domain} && return
read -sp "DB user password:" dbuserp

wp core download --path=${drt}/${domain}/ --allow-root # REDUNDANTS MKDIR
wp config create --path=${drt}/${domain}/ --dbname=${domain} --dbuser=${domain} --dbpass=${dbuserp} --dbhost="localhost" --allow-root

cat ~/myAddons/nginx_app > ${sava}/${domain}.conf
sed -i "s/\${domain}/${1}/g" /${sava}/${domain}.conf

ln -sf ${sava}/${domain}.conf ${sena}
certbot --nginx -d ${domain} -d www.${domain}

chown -R www-data:www-data ${drt}/
chmod -R a-x,a=rX,u+w ${drt}/
/etc/init.d/php*-fpm restart && systemctl restart nginx.service

echo "Please configure DBstack in phpmyadmin."
echo "Please change permissions as you prefer and restart the Nginx server."
```

### Clarification

The conf template I redirect from `~/nginx_app`, for the Nginx app conf, is this one:

```
server {
    root ${drt}/${domain}/;
    server_name ${domain} www.${domain};
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|ttf|woff|pdf)$ { expires 365d; }
}
```

---

Please share your opinion on the above script and adjacent conf file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Shellcheck.net

I strongly recommend to start using https://shellcheck.net/.
Simply copy-paste your script,
and it will tell you many issues with this code.

#### Don't use `return` outside of functions

The `return` statement only works within functions.
You probably meant `exit` instead:

```
domain="$1" && test -z "${domain}" && exit
```

#### Variables in command arguments

Always double-quote variables in command arguments to prevent glob expansion and word splitting, for example:

```
cat ~/myAddons/nginx_app > "${sava}/${domain}.conf"
```

#### Inconsistent paths

Here, the last argument of the second command starts with a `/`, but not the last argument of the first command:

```
cat ~/myAddons/nginx_app > ${sava}/${domain}.conf
sed -i "s/\${domain}/${1}/g" /${sava}/${domain}.conf
```

I suspect the last arguments are intended to be the same in both of these commands. This is confusing.

Comment: Oh thanks! sorry for not editing the question. About the inconsistent path. You meant that it's `/${sava}/${domain}.conf` instead `${sava}/${domain}.conf`? Yes, that's a mistake. About the `chmod`, interesting, I just counted on this example by Stephen Kitt. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416392/combine-find-chmod-for-directories-and-find-chmod-for-regular-files/416393) and also [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416877/what-is-a-capital-x-in-posix-chmod?rq=1), please.